# Изменить значения в DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Необходимо отобразить в таблице значение `'ab'` в столбце `'Type'`, и поделить в них цену на 1000, и сохранить в новый DataFrame.

Реализованный код:

```
df = pd.read_excel('book.xlsx', index_col=None)
df_1 = df[df['Type']=='ab']
df_1.loc['Price'] = df_1.loc['Price']/1000'
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> the label [Price] is not in the [index]

Kак решить проблему?

Исходник залил на [dropmefiles](https://dropmefiles.com/pwMta).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [270]: df2 = df[df['Type']=='ab'].copy()

In [271]: df2
Out[271]:
       Type  Price
markus   ab   6444
vision   ab   8899

In [272]: df2['Price'] /= 1000

In [273]: df2
Out[273]:
       Type  Price
markus   ab  6.444
vision   ab  8.899
```

чтобы изменить строки по условию в исходном DataFrame:

```
In [275]: df.loc[df['Type']=='ab', 'Price'] /= 1000

In [276]: df
Out[276]:
       Type     Price
Avito    fd  8045.000
OLX      bb  5554.000
stada    bb  4566.000
markus   ab     6.444
vision   ab     8.899
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А как следовало бы поступить, если бы отбор был по двум критериям, а уже потом по третьему производить изменения?

Comment: df.loc[(df['Type']=='ab') & (df.Price < 7000), 'Price'] /= 1000

Comment: Супер, благодарю

Comment: А подскажите еще как отобранные по условию строки с `ab` потом заменить на другое значение , например `bb`

Comment: @Max, лучше задать/открыть новый вопрос с небольшим примером данных и ожидаемым результатом... ;)

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, спустя почти год) Тоже столкнулся с этой бедой)